# It takes 2 seconds for my clock to appear on the html page

Tags: javascript, html

I set up 2 files js to create a clock with timing event and html file to show clock.. When I run the html file, it takes 2 seconds for the clock to appear. How to make it run faster??

My code is found below...
HTML file

```js
window.onload = startCurrentTime;

function startCurrentTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var min = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var y = today.getFullYear();
  var mon = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = today.getDate();
  min = checkTime(min);
  s = checkTime(s);
  mon = checkTime(mon);
  d = checkTime(d);
  // document.getElementById('todaylocaltime').innerHTML = "&nbsp;Local Current Date:"+ d + "/" + mon + "/" +y + "&nbsp;Local Current Time:" + h + ":" + min + ":" + s + " SGT ";
  document.getElementById('todaylocaltime').innerHTML = "<font size=3>Current Time " + h + ":" + min + ":" + s + "</font>";
  var t = setTimeout(startCurrentTime, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

```css
font {
  color: black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- <td style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">Events Today: <font></font></td> -->
    <!-- <td style="color:white;">Events Today: <font></font></td> -->
    <td style="color:white;">
      <font size="3">Events Today: </font>
    </td>
    <!-- <td id="totalattack" style="color:white;background-color:#000000;">0 &nbsp;&nbsp;</td> -->
    <td id="totalattack" style="color:white;">
      <font size="3">0</font>
    </td>
    <!-- <td id="todaylocaltime"style="color:white;background-color:#000000;position: absolute; left: 235px;width:300px""></td> -->
    <td id="todaylocaltime" style="color:white;position: absolute; left: 235px;width:300px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

how to make it run faster???I use defer and async to make it run faster. It does not work.......Is it possible to make the clock appear when i reload the page rather than taking some time for the clock to appear.Please help me....thank you

Comment: I wouldn't use the `onload` event. Just call your method immediately with `startCurrentTime()`

Comment: It still takes some time for the clock to appear

Comment: you could try to remove the `startCurrentTime` complete function ... to run the code when it't initialized.

Comment: I do not want to remove the function...

Comment: Hi Can you update snippet with @23tux suggestions. and then we can recreate issue on snippet.

Comment: I don't have any kind of issues with the code provided. Are you trying your code on a toaster?

Comment: @rndus2r , I have many js script in my html file. When I run the html file, it takes some time for the clock to appear

Comment: or at the beginning to run it when the js file loads

Comment: Embed your clock in an iFrame.

Comment: @Rajesh, the error state "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at startCurrentTime" line 15

Comment: @rndus2r, what is the purpose of iFrame???

Comment: @AbdullahShaik my bad! Try `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoad', startCurrentTime)`

Comment: you can try `document.onreadystatechange = function(){if (document.readyState === 'complete'){ startCurrentTime() } }` to run it when the site load is complete

Comment: @Rajesh, the clock does not appear

Comment: It will separate the HTML DOMs, thus, your clock will be independent from the rest of your js, so it will load in an instant.

Comment: @rndus2r , how to do that???

Comment: put the clock into a seperate file and embed it using a frame: `<iframe src="clock.htm">can't load the clock</iframe>`

Comment: @Christian, you mean like this <iframe src="clock.js"></iframe>

Comment: @Christian, i put that code in the head section

Comment: no, you make a HTML file with your table and the HTML file called `clock.htm`. In this file you include the js file with your script tag (`<script src="clock.js"></script>`) Embed this htm file with the IFrame.

Comment: @Abdullah in the head of the frame document, right?

Comment: @Christian, Is there any other way other than iFrame as i do not want to create another htm file

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way :(